# How is sqlalchemy's session used concurrently in the case of fork（uwsgi celery prefork）

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fork

For example, it is found in the development that uwsgi and celery use multiple processes in the way of prefork, but if the session has been created at the time of application initialization, the processes share the same session. How to avoid this situation

Answer (score 0):

A SQLAlchemy session should be short-lived. In a web application, you typically create a session at the start of a request, and remove the session when the request ends.

So each request gets its own session.

Using the session properly is important in SQLAlchemy, I suggest you read this part of the documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html

From [When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it):

> A web application is the easiest case because such an application is
>   already constructed around a single, consistent scope - this is the
>   request, which represents an incoming request from a browser, the
>   processing of that request to formulate a response, and finally the
>   delivery of that response back to the client. Integrating web
>   applications with the Session is then the straightforward task of
>   linking the scope of the Session to that of the request. The Session
>   can be established as the request begins, or using a lazy
>   initialization pattern which establishes one as soon as it is needed.
>   The request then proceeds, with some system in place where application
>   logic can access the current Session in a manner associated with how
>   the actual request object is accessed. As the request ends, the
>   Session is torn down as well, usually through the usage of event hooks
>   provided by the web framework. The transaction used by the Session may
>   also be committed at this point, or alternatively the application may
>   opt for an explicit commit pattern, only committing for those requests
>   where one is warranted, but still always tearing down the Session
>   unconditionally at the end.